# How to get only response data or json ouput from curl

Tags: json, shell, curl, terminal

I'm using the following command to get a JSON response form a source

```
curl --location -g --request POST https://xxxx.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw @D:\RestApi-DB\dbhash.json
```

The response i'm getting is HTML, how can I get a JSON response instead?

I'm running curl command from anaconda on a Windows 10 PC.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think there *is* any JSON to get?

Comment: This can not be reproduced without additional information. How do you expect us to help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please provide examples showing what you're getting, and how you would like that to look.  From the question, it seems not possible to arrive at a solution with the limited information provided.

Comment: Thanks for the response. below is the repsonse now i'm getting from the source.
dont know a day before yesterday it was all html code was appearing. Now it is showing invalid credential. I have asked the concerned team to check.
Thanks.
[code]
(base) C:\Users\nitin>curl --location -g --request POST https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/xxx --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw {"uid":"xxxxx","hash":"xxxxx","timestamp":"1616813558","datasetKey":"xxxxxxx"}

{"status":0,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}
(base) C:\Users\nitin>